# email address validation in JavaScript using regular expression

Tags: javascript, validation, email

I'm currently trying to validate email address using regular expression in JavaScript. These are the requirements of the Email address:

1. The email field contains a user name part follows by "@" and a domain name part.
2. The user name contains word characters including hyphen ("-") and period (".").
3. The domain name contains **two to four** parts of alphabet characters word extension.
4. Each word extension is separated by a period (".") and the last extension must have **two to three** characters.

Among four requirements, the third one is most confusing to me. I will be very appreciate if someone can help me. Thank you.

I have tried the first answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript) page, but this answer accept even 5 or more extensions, so it doesn't meet my third requirement.

Comment: `the last extension must have two to three characters` - old school, you'll exclude many new TLD's

Comment: I think using HTML5 validation would be easier.

Comment: Your requirements are *wrong*, and will reject many valid email addresses.

Comment: Why can't you adapt it then? We don't trade in custom-fitted code, mostly. At least it's not part of the mission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Javascript, here is the regex you need which follows the RFC 5322 standard:

```
/^[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*@([a-z0-9_][-a-z0-9_]*(\.[-a-z0-9_]+)*\.(aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|mil|museum|name|net|org|pro|travel|mobi|[a-z][a-z])|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$/i
```

Side note: it is better to use a very weak regex (basically just matching the '@') and sending a confirmation email.